# In SQL Server, how can I rename a value in a column that is based in a NULL value in another column

Tags: sql-server, group-by, coalesce

I want to rename a single value in one column that is based on the NULL value in another column. I've been thinking about concatenation but I don't know if it will work.

This is the database code.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Purchase_Items]
(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Model_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Brand] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [PurchaseDate] [date] NULL
);

INSERT [dbo].[Purchase_Items] ([ID], [Model_Name], [Brand], [Price], [PurchaseDate]) 
VALUES (5, N'iPhone X', N'Apple', CAST(50000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'2020-02-03' AS Date));

INSERT [dbo].[Purchase_Items] ([ID], [Model_Name], [Brand], [Price], [PurchaseDate]) 
VALUES (6, N'iPhone 11', N'Apple', CAST(70000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'2020-02-07' AS Date));

INSERT [dbo].[Purchase_Items] ([ID], [Model_Name], [Brand], [Price], [PurchaseDate]) 
VALUES (7, N'iPhone 6s', N'Apple', CAST(20000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'2020-02-10' AS Date));

INSERT [dbo].[Purchase_Items] ([ID], [Model_Name], [Brand], [Price], [PurchaseDate]) 
VALUES (8, N'iPhone 8', N'Apple', CAST(30000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'2020-02-21' AS Date));

INSERT [dbo].[Purchase_Items] ([ID], [Model_Name], [Brand], [Price], [PurchaseDate]) 
VALUES (13, N'Redmi 9', N'Xiaomi', CAST(10000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'2020-03-21' AS Date));

INSERT [dbo].[Purchase_Items] ([ID], [Model_Name], [Brand], [Price], [PurchaseDate]) 
VALUES (14, N'Redmi K30', N'Xiaomi', CAST(25000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'2020-04-03' AS Date));

INSERT [dbo].[Purchase_Items] ([ID], [Model_Name], [Brand], [Price], [PurchaseDate]) 
VALUES (15, N'Mi Note 10', N'Xiaomi', CAST(15000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'2020-04-21' AS Date));

INSERT [dbo].[Purchase_Items] ([ID], [Model_Name], [Brand], [Price], [PurchaseDate]) 
VALUES (16, N'BlackShark', N'Xiaomi', CAST(30000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'2020-04-20' AS Date));

INSERT [dbo].[Purchase_Items] ([ID], [Model_Name], [Brand], [Price], [PurchaseDate]) 
VALUES (17, N'iPhone 11', N'Apple', CAST(70000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'2020-04-22' AS Date));

INSERT [dbo].[Purchase_Items] ([ID], [Model_Name], [Brand], [Price], [PurchaseDate]) 
VALUES (18, N'iPhone 11', N'Apple', CAST(70000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'2020-05-03' AS Date));

INSERT [dbo].[Purchase_Items] ([ID], [Model_Name], [Brand], [Price], [PurchaseDate]) 
VALUES (22, N'iPhone 8', N'Apple', CAST(30000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'2020-05-21' AS Date));

INSERT [dbo].[Purchase_Items] ([ID], [Model_Name], [Brand], [Price], [PurchaseDate]) 
VALUES (23, N'BlackShark 3', N'Xiaomi', CAST(30000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'2020-05-22' AS Date));

INSERT [dbo].[Purchase_Items] ([ID], [Model_Name], [Brand], [Price], [PurchaseDate]) 
VALUES (25, N'iPhone X', N'Apple', CAST(70000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'2020-05-10' AS Date));
```

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(PurchaseDate) Month,
    COALESCE(Brand, 'Monthly Subtotal') AS Brand,
    SUM(Price) AS 'Total Amount'
FROM 
    Purchase_Items
GROUP BY 
    CUBE(MONTH(PurchaseDate), Brand)
```

This is what I would expect it to look:

```
Purchase Month   |         Brand           | Total Amount
---------------------------------------------------------
        3        |         Xiaomi          |   10000.00 
        4        |         Xiaomi          |   70000.00
        5        |         Xiaomi          |   30000.00
       NULL      | Grand Total for Xiaomi  |  110000.00
        2        |         Apple           |  170000.00
        4        |         Apple           |   70000.00
        5        |         Apple           |  170000.00
       NULL      | Grand Total for Apple   |  410000.00           
       NULL      |       Grand Total       |  520000.00
        1        |     Monthly Subtotal    |  250000.00
        2        |     Monthly Subtotal    |  200000.00
        3        |     Monthly Subtotal    |   70000.00
```

But instead of 'Grand Total for Xiaomi', and 'Grand Total for Apple'
I get 'Xiaomi' and 'Apple'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Checking into the `grouping()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a conditional statement in SQL. That could be done by CASE. However, since you have a `group by` statement it is better to do it in an outer select statement. CONCAT() is the function in SQL Server for concatenating two strings.

```
SELECT 
   Month, 
   CASE
      WHEN Month is Null THEN CONCAT('Grand Total for', Brand)
      ELSE Brand
   END AS newBrand,
   'Total Amount'
FROM(
   SELECT 
      MONTH(PurchaseDate) Month,
      COALESCE(Brand, 'Monthly Subtotal') AS Brand,
      SUM(Price) AS 'Total Amount'
   FROM 
      Purchase_Items
   GROUP BY 
      CUBE(MONTH(PurchaseDate), Brand)
)
```